# Publish to Azure Service Bus Topic with AMQP using username and password

Tags: .net, azure, amqp, activemq-artemis

I'm dealing with a system implemented in .Net using AMPQ to publish messages to an ActiveMQ Artemis instance using a username and password, along with host, port, and protocol, e.g.:

```
amqps://guest:guest@this.com:1234
```

I'd like to change the settings and point it to a topic on an Azure Service Bus instance. Azure SB allows you to setup a Shared Access Policy, which provides a connection string and key.

```
Endpoint=sb://[hostname]/;SharedAccessKeyName=[name]Key;SharedAccessKey=[key]
```

So how do I setup access in Azure to allow a system to connect like this?

Comment: Hope this reference [helps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-integrate-with-rabbitmq)

Comment: AFAIK, there are no direct method or connection parameters to connect with `RabbitMQ Shovel AMQP Connection String` in C#, but you can publish a message to the queue using C# by connecting the [queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-integrate-with-rabbitmq#enabling-the-rabbitmq-shovel-plugin) or topic with `amqps://rabbitmq-shovel:StringOfRandomChars@rabbitmq.servicebus.windows.net:5671/?sasl=plain`.

Comment: This all looks specific to RabbitMQ. I'm dealing with ActiveMQ Artemis.